# FormGroup.reset() does not update value in DOM

Tags: angular, forms, dom

I've built a form with the angular FormBuilder.

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {}

searchForm = this.fb.group({
  firstName: [],
  lastName: [],
  age: [18]
});
```

As part of a form reset I want to clear all values in the form but reset the default value of age back to `18`. So in my template I've tied my `<form>` to the form group with

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  ...
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
  <button type="reset" (click)="reset()">Clear</button>
</form>
```

And the `reset()` function is as such.

```
reset() {
  this.searchForm.reset({age: 18});
}
```

What am I missing, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a value such as described in the [doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset)

In your case :

```
reset() {
  this.searchForm.reset({age : 18});
}
```

## **EDIT**

You had `type="reset"` which seems to override the default value.
Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oamkoc)

Comment: Ya that updates the form values, but it doesn't update the DOM (or template) it seems.

Comment: The `type="reset"` was it. Thank you sir.